# How to change IP of VPN interface?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ip, network-interface

I have connected to a VPN on Ubuntu. and type `ifconfig` shows VPN interface has an IP of 10.10.0.11. Unfortunately, there is another computer in my lan whose ip is also 10.10.0.11 and they're conflicted.
I want to change this, but how?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/335352/how-to-change-ip-address-in-ubuntu-desktop-through-command-line

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of that question.  @demonguy: When you say you have connected to a VPN on Ubuntu, does that mean that Ubuntu is the server for the VPN connection, or that it is a client for some other VPN connection?  If it is a client, then you may not have much control over your IP address unless you can coordinate with the server's administrator.

Comment: In my case, i connected to remote VPN server from my ubuntu computer. And i don't have any control over VPN server.  Does it mean i can't change the IP shows in `ifconfig` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you cannot change the ip of the VPN interface, as it is being given to you by the oposite site. Given that 10.x is a class A network, you usually don't have a Class A network on both sides, which makes me wonder how you ended up with a class A network you're currently in. Either ask the opposite side to change their network, or change yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of them are impossible. I bought VPN service from internet, of course i can't change theirs, and my office lan network also user 10.X.X.X, and i can't change this either.

Comment: If you bought VPN service, I'm pretty sure you can email support and explain the situation. A VPN should always be in a separate IP range, and they'll understand that. I bet it will be a matter of changing a setting for you.